# Value of type 'String' has no member 'range' in Swift

Tags: swift

I believe I've run into a Swift versioning issue but I'm not too sure.  The code works in my Xcode platform but not in an online swift compiler.  Has anyone else run into this issue or know what I can use to replace the following lines where I check for a character:

```
if i == 0 || !((line.range(of: ":") != nil))
```

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation



func hackTheString(line: String){

        var maxOpen: Int = 0
        var minOpen: Int = 0

        minOpen = 0
        maxOpen = 0
        let i = 0
        while i < line.characters.count {
            for character in line.characters {
                if character == "(" {
                    maxOpen += 1
                    if i == 0 || !((line.range(of: ":") != nil)) {
                        minOpen += 1
                        }
                    }
                else if character == ")"{
                    minOpen = max(0,minOpen-1)

                    if i == 0 || !((line.range(of: ":") != nil)){
                        maxOpen -= 1;
                        }
                    if maxOpen < 0{
                        break
                    }
                }
            }

        if maxOpen >= 0 && minOpen == 0{
            print("YES")
            }else{
                print("NO")
            }
        }
    }


while let line = readLine() {


    print(hackTheString(line))

}
```

The error given from the online compiler is:

```
source.swift:17:37: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'range'
                    if i == 0 || !((line.range(of: ":") != nil)) {
                                    ^~~~ ~~~~~
source.swift:24:37: error: value of type 'String' has no member 'range'
                    if i == 0 || !((line.range(of: ":") != nil)){
                                    ^~~~ ~~~~~
```

Comment: Does the online service you're using give a specific error? If it does please include that in your question.

Comment: Sorry about that @MathewS

Comment: Sounds like your online compiler is using Swift 2. Try `line.rangeOfString(":").

Comment: And why do you have `!((line.range(of: ":") != nil))` ? That's the same as `line.range(of: ":") == nil`. Why double-negative? Why the extra set of parentheses?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I'll try that and Xcode made the suggestion and I was so eager to see the error go away to try testing it.  Right now I'm scratching my head to find out where I went wrong for it to return my answer over and over.

Comment: I fixed the code by adding break statements and by adding the line.range function brought up another error that says type string has no member range.@rmaddy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried using `range(of:)` function on IBM's online swift compiler and I made sure to write `import Foundation` and it totally worked. Then I tried to see what version of swift is that online compiler using with following code:

```
#if swift(>=3.0)
print("Hello, Swift 3!")
#elseif swift(>=2.2)
print("Hello, Swift 2.2!")
#elseif swift(>=2.1)
print("Hello, Swift 2.1!")
#endif
```

That way I got to know that the online compiler I tried was using Swift 3 and hence the function worked perfect. Try checking what version your online compiler is using and use the related function specific to that version.

Other thing that you can do for now is use the characters array of your string and find the `Index` of your character. So your code might look like this:

```
if i == 0 || !((line.characters.index(of: ":") != nil)) {
                        minOpen += 1          
}
```

Comment: Thanks @The Rohan Sanap however it won't allow me to check for the Swift version.  When I make the recommended changes it produces a new error that reads: "error: value of type 'String.CharacterView' has no member 'index'".  I do have import Foundation in place as well

Comment: @user6510422 Form what you said in comment above, I suspect your compiler uses Swift 2.x. Try using function `line.characters.indexOf(":")`