# Filtering 'string' values of elements in array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, ubuntu, filter

As I am just starting my adventure with programming in general and with Swift in particular I am unable to solve my problem with filtering an array.

While working with my book, I got to a chapter where arrays are explained and
I had no problem with working with arrays untill now. Here is a code from my student's book :

```
var city = ["Boston", "London", "Chicago", "Atlanta"]
let filtered = city.filter{$0.range(of:"o") != nil}
```

This is supposed to filter the cities with the letter "o" in it but when compiled this message is being shown :

```
error: value of type 'String' has no member 'range
```

So does it mean that I can't use `.range` for string values?
What chould the code look like then?
I am using ubuntu as my OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you `import Foundation`?

Comment: No, I am working with a book and as the book didn't tell me to do it I didn't
To this point of the book I didnt have to import anything or there wasn't even a word written in it about importing anything.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41517343/7250862 .And you can use `contains` to check whether a `string` has a `character` `let filtered = city.filter{$0.contains("o")}`

Comment: Without importing Foundation: `let filtered = city.filter{$0.characters.contains("o")}`

Comment: @vacawama Yes, this works too. Thank you.

Comment: @Hamish I meant for this question, sorry. so I mean I am trying to substract items from both sets set1 and set2 and the compiler shows the same error as in the question above only with that .range is replaced with .substracting

Comment: @Bodeue Same comment I'm afraid – it's hard to know what the problem is without seeing the code (it's not an import issue, as it's part of the standard library itself). You should ask a new question.

Comment: @Hamish okay, apparently I am dumb and wrote substract instead of subtract (english is not my native language)

Answer (score 2):

<s>You are getting this error because unfortunately `range` is not available in Linux. If you had access to a machine with `macOS` this would work.</s>

As @Hamish said, I was completely wrong, you have to import `Foundation` in order to use `range` or `contains` on `String` (even though you can call `contains` on `string.characters` without importing `Foundation`).

Add this line to the beginning of your code:

```
import Foundation
```

Comment: I tried the OP's code on that sandbox too and got the same error, even though it worked fine on a playground in Xcode 8.3 / Swift 3.1

Comment: The book I am working with is dedicated for programming in linux in particular so could it be it is the authors mistake?

Comment: No, @Bodeue, @Hamish was right, you have to import `Foundation`, check my edit.

Comment: Thank you, it solved it. Now I will wonder why did I have to import anything and what this "Foundation" thing is. I hope it will be explained in the book later.